# How to inject a DummyRepository into Android app?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, mocking, mockito, code-injection

I have implemented an interface for a repository "MessageRepository". 
I now want to select two different configurations to run the app.  One where the app runs normally and one for test mode where the app also runs, but instead of an actual Database there is a DummyRepository used?

For this purpose I do not want to change any code in the existing app's code.

I am fairly new to Mocks (using Mockito) and testing in general. Also I do not really understand what injection is, so how do I do this?

Comment: Mocking frameworks are meant for unit testing; just define the `DummyRepository` yourself.

Comment: Well it would be perfectly fine if I just write a DummyRepository. The problem I have is how do I define it to be used without hardcoding it into the app code?

Comment: And what's the problem with that? The other classes are hard-coded as well. And the wiring/configuration of your components into an object graph into the composition root is hard-coded as well.

Comment: Well say my data is coming from a web-service, which is under maintenance and thus unconnectable. Now I want to develop my app design. 

Respectively I want to develop my app while I am on a flight and can not use any internet.

Now I do not want to have to change my code, but instead I want to change the configuration under which it is run (by configuration I mean the drop down menu on the top) and I want to keep developing.

Comment: Can we see the code on where you want to use the `DummyRepository` and `MessageRepository`?